# System._ComObject is not convert.... Why this Exception?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object, byte

```
I purpose, turn obj into byte array objects. But serialize method is error
```

Dim obj As Object = Nothing
    Dim data As Byte()
    obj = getDocument(pid)             'getdocument(pid)-->Type:Object , obj.value=System._Object
    data = ObjectToByteArray(obj)

*****upper code Form_Load*****

```
**Public Function ObjectToByteArray(obje As Object) As Byte()**    
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()    
Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter()    
bf.Serialize(ms, obje)              ******Exeption Error**
Return ms.ToArray()    
**End Function**
```

my exception is: Type 'System._ComObject' in Assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as seializable

Comment: COM objects are never binary serializable, there's no point in trying.  It *might* implement IPersistStream, odds are never good.  You will have to avoid solving this XY problem.

Comment: thank you, I try PersistStream in vb.net

Comment: Also, do you know; how can I see System.ComObject details? @HansPassant